# jquery draggable plugin works in chrome with defect

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, jquery-plugins, draggable

I use jquery draggable plugin, this is my easy code

```
$(document).ready( function () {

    $("#my_div").draggable();           

});
```

In html

```
 <div id="my_div" style="width: 100px; height: 100px; background-color: #090"> </div>
```

problem is this: when I start drag, the object automatically jumped top, approximately 20 px.
at every movement of the element, the element jumped top.
This unexpectedly jump happens only in google chrome, in other browsers draggable works good. My chrome version is last and I test this in 2 various computer and in both computer this "top jump" happened only in chrome. Someone know why? and how solve this problem in chrome?

Comment: Here it does work great, in both safari and chrome (Mac OS). Maybe you should make a jsfiddle, perhaps the problem is somewhere else

Comment: here is example for draggable, this in my chrome works with "top jump" defect
http://d25221763.u-telcom.net/

Comment: as I said, it works fine here, sorry, can't help